# Capistrano post deploy uglify-js hook outputs but doesn't write files

Tags: javascript, capistrano, minify, uglifyjs

I'm facing a strange issue, that surely isn't difficult, but I can't seem to find out what's causing it. After deploying my app via Capistrano, I'm passing all my css through the yui compressor, using :

```
 run "find #{current_path}/public/static/css/ -name '*.css' -print0 | xargs -0 -I file #{cmd} file -o file"
```

A quick look around and a few tests made me decide to use node's uglify-js for JavaScript compression, so I went for a simple

```
uglify_bin = "uglifyjs"
run "find #{current_path}/public/static/js/ -type f -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 #{uglify_bin}"
```

in the same recipe. Deployment seems to go fine, but a quick inspection at my js files shows uglifyjs didn't do it's job.

Here's an extract of the console output :

```
  * executing "find /home/USER/www/project/current/public/static/js/ -type f -name '*.js'| xargs uglifyjs --overwrite"
servers: ["project.com"]
[project.com] executing command
command finished in 127ms
```

Where am I being a complete idiot (yes, it's the word...) ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found what the probleme was. Here's the line of code the way it finally works :

```
run "find #{current_path}/public/static/js/ -name '*.js'| xargs -I file #{uglify_path} --overwrite file"
```

Obviously, the --overwrite option wasn't were it should have been...

Answer (score 0):

From the uglifyjs [docs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS):

> --overwrite — if the code is read from a file (not from STDIN) and you pass --overwrite then the output will be written in the same file.

So perhaps something like:

```
uglify_bin = "uglifyjs"
run "find #{current_path}/public/static/js/ -type f -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 #{uglify_bin} --overwrite"
```

Will work.

Comment: Believe it or not, I did read the doc, and allready tried that. Unfortunately, didn't do the job.

Comment: Does uglifyjs support getting more than one filename as an argument at at time? If not, it may only be processing the first JS file. Perhaps you can try adding -n1 to your xargs command:

run "find #{current_path}/public/static/js/ -type f -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 #{uglify_bin}" --overwrite

Also, does it work if you run the find command manually?

Comment: Not any better. More frustrating, when I do a uglifyjs bootstrap.js > bootstrap.min.js , new file is created, and perfectly compressed. I'm puzzled...

Comment: And when you manually run uglifyjs --overwrite bootstrap.js - does it work and replace the contents of the original bootstrap.js file?

Comment: So the problem is with the way the command is executed from Capistrano. Are you able to check the return code and/or the command output from Capistrano? I am not very familiar with Capistrano, but from the looks of it it looks like it is running the command remotely on the project.com server. Are you sure the uglifyjs command is installed correctly there and is in the $PATH?